# WordPress not loading after moving from non-www to www

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have updated my WordPress URL in General settings from `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com`.

Also, put this redirect code in `.htaccess` as well:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

When entered naked example.com, I am able to see it is being redirected to www.example.com, but site is not loading.
Even if I enter the www.example.com directly.

Comment: are you able to access the admin panel?

Comment: what the error message it is showing? toomany redirects or site cant be reached

Comment: @VinothRaja, no `wp-admin` is also not accessible.

Comment: @charankumar, I see a blank white page only

Comment: enable this `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in wp-config and check for any errors.

Comment: @theKing first take backup the DB & code and then change the wp-option table siteurl & homeurl value with out https (http://example.com) and then delete the .htaccess file. May be once after done the above changes you will allow to access the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the database also. Go to the database and check the site URL and home page URL in the wp-options table.